# How to convert properties hash table to string data in powershell?

Tags: powershell, properties

I have a properties file, with data below.

```
dbport=5432
dcname=
dbssl=false
locktime=300
```

To update it from powershell, I loaded it from file and converted it as below.

```
$configuration = ConvertFrom-StringData($data)
echo $configuration

Name                           Value                                                                                                                                                          
----                           -----                                                                                                                                                          
dbport                    5432                                                                                                                                                      
dbname                                                                                                                                                                            
dbssl                       false                                                                                                                                                        
locktime                    300
```

But how to convert this to original format to write back.

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming that `$configuration` is an hashtable. So you could iterate over the items of hash table and construct the rows with the same format. You can then use *`Out-File`* Cmdlet to write the content back to the file.

```
$configuration.keys | ForEach-Object { "$_=$($configuration.$_)"} | Out-File -FilePath "<YOUR_PATH>"
```